# set margin/padding in between table columns without changing each columns width

Tags: html, css

On full screen I have 3 columns and I am trying to make the columns have padding/margin in between each columns. When I set the margin to the following:

```
margin: 0 25px;
```

The third columns goes below the other two.. My code is the following:

```
<div class="landscape-row">
  <div class="landscape-column">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"  style="width:100%">  
    <h1>example heading</h1>
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="landscape-column">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"  style="width:100%">  
    <h1>example heading</h1>
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  <div class="landscape-column">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500"  style="width:100%">  
    <h1>example heading</h1>
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is the following:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.landscape-row{
width:100%;
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;
}
.landscape-column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 5px;

    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.landscape-row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    padding: 10px;

}

img{
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
padding-top:20px;
}

h1{
text-align:center;
}

p{
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
text-align:center;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    .landscape-column {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .landscape-column:last-child{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .landscape-column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Below is a JS Fiddle of what I have
https://jsfiddle.net/tos3y2jk/3/

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why don’t you put a div inside each table cell and then put the padding or margin on that?

Comment: I have just tried that but still hasn't worked

Comment: it Could be the way you implemented it. Try making a stripped down version with minimal code and build it up bit by bit. No reason why it should not work. Once you have a cut down version if it does not work post it on here and let me know

Comment: I've managed to solve my problem (almost). The right side has slightly more padding to the left when in a row of 3 only.. here is the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tos3y2jk/39/ if you could have a quick look to see what is causing this?

Comment: I don't see that extra padding - it all looks even to me? I was using the computed tab in the chrome developer tools

Comment: This seems to have fixed it https://jsfiddle.net/tos3y2jk/47/ the issue was with the landscape-row width.. I had to use calc(100% + 25px).. would it be possible to explain why this was needed?

Comment: Sorry, that is not something I know about